# How to restore WhatsApp backup file?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore

My phone's screen is broken, but I recovered the SIM card (phone number) and WhatsApp backup file: `msgstore.db.crypt14` (using USB debug). I don't have a WhatsApp backup on Google Drive.

When I open WhatsApp on the new phone, I can't find any option to select the backup file that I copied to the internal memory. Not even after reinstalling WhatsApp and recreating the directory from where I copied it in the root of the internal memory: `/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt14`.

Is this file really useful for something? The WhatsApp itself does not appear to be able to open it. How to restore the WhatsApp backup file?

Comment: The question didn't mention the Android version of the old and new phone, but since Android 11, WhatsApp stores its files in a different folder. You might want to also check there.

Comment: The old is 8, the new is 13. I think you probably right, i will try new things as soon i can, thx.